# Conditional error handling in bash depending on exit code

Tags: bash

I am trying to achieve error handling for a bash command. Consider following command -

```
export FOO=$(some_command_that_returns_exit_code | base64 --decode)
```

I want to make it so that if

```
some_command_that_returns_exit_code
```

exits with non zero code, it should exit without piping or storing to a variable FOO. 
At the same time, if it succeeds, it should pipe to decode and store the output to FOO.

**However, I need to do this without rerunning some_command_that_returns_exit_code. (I know it's pretty easy if I am allowed to run the command twice)**

As far as I understand, there is no way to achieve this.
If you are wondering about scenario where this could be useful, substitute for *some_command_that_returns_exit_code* could be an *aws s3* command that we can't rerun due to API rate limit issues etc.

Comment: `$?` will contain the exit code of the last command run. You could store the returned data in a temp variable. Check `$?` and then export it based on the exit code.

Comment: `export` has its own success or failure state, so it overrides `$?`. This is already in the knowledge base. You can run `foo=$(whatever); foo_rc=$?; export foo` as separate commands. See [BashPitfalls #27](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#local_varname.3D.24.28command.29)